# How to send stderr to stdout with a pipe to another command?

Tags: linux, command-line, pipe, make, stdout

I'm trying to capture all of the output of a build operation, and send it to `myprogram`. I seem to only be able to capture part of it. This is what I'm trying:

```
make clean && make DISABLE_ID3TAG=1 CFLAGS="-O2 -DNDEBUG -W64" | myprogram &2 > 1
```

I also tried:

```
make clean && make DISABLE_ID3TAG=1 CFLAGS="-O2 -DNDEBUG -W64" &2 > 1 | myprogram
```

Basically I want to send everything to `stdout` and then do something with that. Currently I'm only capturing part of the output, and the other part is going to the screen. How can I pipe everything to another program?

Comment: It should be noted that the `&2>1` syntax is bash specific. For instanche in `tcsh` I would write `|&`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you have two commands, it would be better to use:

```
{ make clean && make DISABLE_ID3TAG=1 CFLAGS="-O2 -DNDEBUG -W64"; } 2>&1 | myprogram
```

Or

```
( make clean && make DISABLE_ID3TAG=1 CFLAGS="-O2 -DNDEBUG -W64" ) 2>&1 | myprogram
```

The `make clean` is not directing its output to the pipe, you will want to use either of the two above to let the shell redirect the output of both `make` calls as one.

Answer (score 2):

You need to redirect STDERR to STDOUT for all the commands. Then you can pipe it all into `myprogram`.

```
( make clean 2>&1 && make DISABLE_ID3TAG=1 CFLAGS="-O2 -DNDEBUG -W64" 2>&1 ) | myprogram
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(make clean && make DISABLE_ID3TAG=1 CFLAGS="-O2 -DNDEBUG -W64") 2>&1 | myprogram
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of myprogram, you could also try passing your make op to the myprogram, wherein you read the stdout and stderr as separate stream.

It depends on how complicated you want to make myprogram.

The main advantage is being able to handle stdout and stderr independently instead of lumped together.